# Why PostMessage with WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK does not work?

Tags: c++, winapi

I run this code:

```
LPPOINT pp = new POINT;
GetCursorPos(pp);
while(1){
    PostMessage(GetDesktopWindow(), WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK, 0, MAKELPARAM(pp->x, pp->y));
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

It does not click on the point indicated by the cursor, but opens and closes the Start menu
.Please tell me what's wrong

Comment: Can you tell more about the environment? Is it a GUI or a CLI app? That is important to know if GetCursor will return client window or screen coordinates. If you stop in the debugger, what is the value of pp? I suppose it's 0, 0, which means a click on Start Menu. Note that you don't update the position of the cursor because GetCursorPos is outside of the while loop. And you should not use dynamic memory for this, POINT p = {0}; GetCursorPos(&p); would be better.

Comment: Why would you expect this to work. This is not how to automate the shell.

Comment: @z32a7ul pp is contain absolute coordinates of screen (my screen size is 1920x1080). thanks for your remark, i moved GetCursosPos to while(1) cycle

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why? GetDesktopWindow is retrieves a desktop hwnd and PostMessage takes a hwnd

Comment: @sddvxd Because `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` is a **response** to a mouse click, it does not **cause** a mouse click.

Comment: I think you should ask about your actual goal. You aren't actually interested in posting that message for its own sake. You want to make something happen. What is that thing?

Comment: @john Ok. then WM_CLOSE is also the answer to closing the application? or should WM_CLOSE be sent by the initiator of the closure?

Comment: @john 
I read, really, this is the way you describe

Comment: Instead of giving us what you think are the solutions to your problem, please tell us about the problem. Sending `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` message to the desktop window isn't going to be the solution to any problem. But we can't help you beyond that because you didn't ask about the problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan 
I have a task - to play a double click on the remote desktop (opening applications and the rest of the work on the end-user computer). I'm looking for a way to send double click

Comment: Fake input using SendInput. Not sure if faking input is the best way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` to an arbitrary window handle or to the desktop will not simulate a mouse click.

You can use [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput), however, which can simulate a mouse click given screen coordinates (not a window handle, or window or client coordinates). This code will simulate a left-button click at the current cursor position:

```
INPUT in[2]; // 0 = left dn, 1 = left up
ZeroMemory(in, sizeof(INPUT) * 2);

in[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
in[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;

in[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
in[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;

SendInput(2, in, sizeof(INPUT));
```

Note that you can also use [`mouse_event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event), but `SendInput` is preferred according to the official documentation on MSDN.